# How to change Webpack-simple to Webpack in a Vue application?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, deployment

I have created a vue application without realising that webpack-simple is unsuitable for deployment. Is there a way to change this to webpack without having to create a new project?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Here is the server.js code where i think we are getting the error.

```
// server.js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const serveStatic = require('serve-static');

const app = express();
//app.use(serveStatic(path.join(__dirname + '/dist')));
app.use(serveStatic(path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/build.js')));

console.log("RESOLVED PATH " + path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/build.js'));

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port)
```

Comment: this one? https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple

Comment: yeah so i have a project set up with this at the moment but i am unable to deploy, i need to swap the template from webpack-simple to webpack. so from the link you gave to this one https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack

Comment: What are the problems you are having to deploy webpack-simple?

Comment: We are trying to serve the application through a mini express server and keep getting Cannot Get / as an error -  see the updated question for the server.js code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working with a change to the script.js file.

This is the script.js file that worked in the end.

```
// server.js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const serveStatic = require('serve-static');

const app = express();
app.use(serveStatic(__dirname));

console.log("RESOLVED PATH " + path.join(__dirname, 'dist'));

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port);

console.log('server started '+ port);
```

The change that got it working was changing this line

```
app.use(serveStatic(path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/build.js')));
```

To this

```
app.use(serveStatic(__dirname));
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets rework on top of what webpack-simple provides you.

You will need index.html and also the dist folder,  closer to this server file.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.resolve('.')));

app.all('*', (req, res) => {
  res.send('index.html');
})

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port)
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I actually got it working using the answer I just posted

Comment: well, to be honest, that is basically what i posted, but using the serve-static library! I'm glad it worked!

Comment: Thanks again for helping! managed to get it working before i had seen your answer, could have saved me a lot of time haha